# Print output in form from out.print() statement in JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am running my program on Apache Server.
As of now I comment the second form to get the output as normal text.

But I want to use the second form as the output table.

I need help in JSP file while using `out.print()`

How can I pass the output from `out.print()` to second form?

***SWAPPING OF TWO NUMBERS***

LAB11.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>LAB11</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
            background-color: white;
            width: 20%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;  
            margin: auto;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        input[type=text] {
        padding:5px; 
        border:2px solid #ccc; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus {
        border-color:#333;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
        padding:5px 15px; 
        background:#ccc; 
        border:0 none;
        cursor:pointer;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; 
        }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="BlanchedAlmond">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;font-size: 30px;color:crimson">Swapping of two numbers</h1>
    <div>
    <form action="LAB11_1.jsp">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="n1"></td><br>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Second Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="n2"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Swap"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>

    <h1 style="text-align: center;font-size: 30px;color:crimson">After Swapping</h1>
    <div>
    <form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="n3" id="n3"></td><br>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Second Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="n4" id="n4"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>ss

    </body>
    </html>
```

LAB11_1.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>LAB11_1</title>
</head>
<body> 

<%
int a=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
int b=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n2"));

    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a-b;

    out.print(a+"<br>");
    out.print(b+"<br>");
%> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you rather make it clear what you want to do??
You want both input and output on same page or different page??
And if same page then it it compulsory to use `out.println` or javascript is fine???